# No such column 'HasCommentsUnreadByOwner'/'HasSelfServiceComments' on entity 'Case'

Tags: soql, case

I'm facing an issue with Case field 'HasCommentsUnreadByOwner' and 'HasSelfServiceComments'. When I execute the query in an apex class or query editor:

```
Select Id, HasSelfServiceComments, HasCommentsUnreadByOwner From Case LIMIT 10
```

I get the following error for both the fields:

```
No such column 'HasCommentsUnreadByOwner' on entity 'Case'. If you are 
attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the
custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for 
the appropriate names.
```

or

```
No such column 'HasSelfServiceComments' on entity 'Case'. If you are 
attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the
custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for 
the appropriate names.
```

I'm not sure why this is not working. As in the documentation, these are the Boolean fields in Case Object that are defaulted on Create, Filter, Group or Sort functions.

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_case.htm

How to query these fields? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I ran this query in few orgs, I'm getting this error in my Winter '15 org. It pulls the value in all orgs created in the past.

Comment: When I query these fields using  DevConsole as admin I got the results.

Comment: @Suri Oh! Even I'm querying as an admin. So, any setting or permission has to be enabled?

Comment: I tried it too, successfully. It's almost certainly an org-specific issue, possibly an API version conflict? If you resolve it please do post the resolution.

Comment: @Bri You are right. Even I tried in another Prod env and it's retrieving the field values.

Comment: Do you have a portal/community active in this org? Those fields may not be available unless you have a reason for them.

Comment: @CyberJus Oh Yes. I have an active community in this org.

Comment: I just checked a new (Spring15) dev org and I do not have the fields there either.

Comment: Same in Spring '15 enterprise too.